# Get path to capistrano shared path from ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, capistrano3

I know that I can get the location of my rails app with `Rails.root`:

```
> Rails.root
 => #<Pathname:/var/www/app-name/releases/20150507181426>
```

I am looking for the function to call to get capistrano's shared folder, which in this case is found here:

```
/var/www/app-name/shared/
```

I need to be able to get the path from within ruby code.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really shouldn't need to know what Capistrano's shared path is. During the deployment process it's expected that you'll create links to any directories that are shared between deployments.

The `linked_dirs` variable defines this:

```
set :linked_dirs, %w[ example ]
```

If set, during deployment `releases/NNN/example` will be linked to `shared/example`. You can add or alter this list as required.

**Update:**

If you're concerned about this symlink being removed as subsequent deployments are applied, it's worthwhile to expand this link to the full path by whatever process uses it before exercising that.

Following these links is the most reliable way to get to the proper destination.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The purpose of my question is to pass the shared path to another program via ruby.  I've got `:linked_dirs` setup correctly and I'm using it correctly but I wanted to sent the absolute path because the simlink will disappear after a few updates.  I was thinking there would be a variable/function I could use, but maybe I'll have to just convert the relative to absolute path manually?

Comment: Linked directories won't disappear, you can always reference `current/example` in this case. If you're paranoid, which is not always a bad thing, you can expand this link to the full path as necessary. That won't disappear even if you deploy a hundred times.

Comment: Sorry, I misstated that.  The linked directory will not disappear, but rather the simlink to it will.  Expanding to the full path may be the way to go, if you update your answer to include that, I'll make this the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use the global capistrano variable `shared_path` (works on capistrano v2 and v3).

It provide you the base path of your shared stuff:

```
puts "#{shared_path}"
=> /DEPLOY_PATH/APP_NAME/shared
```

A list of possible useful global variables can be found [here](http://theadmin.org/articles/capistrano-variables/), I guess that most of them work well in capistrano v3 too.

---

UPDATE

Just note that most of them are only available under the capistrano libs (`deploy.rb` or the custom stages: `development.rb`,`staging.rb`, `production.rb`,...) or in the capistrano rake tasks (when using for example the `on role(:app) do {...}`callback).

Comment: Typing in `puts "#{shared_path}"` to a ruby console gives me `NameError: undefined local variable or method `shared_path' for main:Object`.  Are you able to run this from your ruby console?

Comment: @RickSmith yep you have right, in a classic console `rails console` they are not defined, they are only available under some condition (see updated answer). You can check there using for a example a must have (in my opinion ;)) gem: https://github.com/pry/pry and looking there